# Dijkstra step-by-step

Tags: algorithm

I've been following Dijkstra's algorithm step by step from http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~angelia/ge330fall09_dijkstra_l18.pdf

However with my own example, I don't find the shortest path if I stop as soon as I reach the destination node.

I'm going to look for the shortest path from A -> E as below:

[image]

And I traverse as follows:

[image]

This gives me the shortest path of A->F->E which is incorrect (the shortest path is C->D->E).

The difficulty being that I never inspect D.

But I've read (not least in the link above) that you can stop inspecting nodes as soon as you reach the destination. How is this true?

Comment: The distance is calculated correctly. How did you arrive to the path itself?

Comment: @n.m. The distance is not correct, the shortest distance is 11.

Comment: The calculated distance is A-F-E which is 17, the correct should be C-D-E which is 11

Comment: @Henry yeah I see now. The power of large images on a phone.

Comment: Sorry for using the images. I also found it problematic to use text for issues like this and don't have an ideal solution to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stopped too early. Continue the algorithm until E is selected as the current node.